# Conditionally set padding to certain number, but otherwise set to 'default' in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to set the padding only if a certain condition is true, otherwise it should be whatever the default inherited value is.

ie,

```
<View style={{paddingTop: myCondition ? 19 : 'default value?'  }}> 
   // ...
</View>
```

Is there a way I can do this inside that `style` tag? The only other way I can think to do this is to duplicate `<View>` and have separate conditions where one is true, the other is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `style` prop accepts an array of styles, and if any of the values are falsy, they are discarded. This means you can use the `&&` operator to conditionally render a style, or nothing, in which case default style is applied.

```
<View style={[ myCondition && {paddingTop: 19} ]}>
```

If you have other styles, you can place them in the same array:

```
<View style={[ 
    { padding: 10 },
    myCondition && {paddingTop: 19} 
]}>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={(condition)? {paddingTop: 19} : {'default value'}}> 
   // ...
</View>
```